# Can’t Send @metadata to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to include @metadata field contents in my elasticsearch output.
This is the output when i am using stdout in my output filter-

```
{
"@timestamp" => 2018-03-08T08:17:42.059Z,
"thread_name" => "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2",
"@metadata" => {
"dead_letter_queue" => {
"entry_time" => 2018-03-08T08:17:50.082Z,
"reason" => "Could not index event to Elasticsearch. status: 400, action: ["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"applog-2018.03.08", :_type=>"doc", :_routing=>nil}, #LogStash::Event:0x3ab79ab5], response: {"index"=>{"_index"=>"applog-2018.03.08", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"POuwBGIB0PJDPQOoDy1Q", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [message]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:223"}}}}",
"plugin_type" => "elasticsearch",
"plugin_id" => "7ee60ceccc2ef7c933cf5aa718d42f24a65b489e12a1e1c7b67ce82e04ef0d37"
}
},
"@version" => "1",
"beat" => {
"name" => "filebeat-kwjn6",
"version" => "6.0.0"
},
"dateOffset" => 408697,
"source" => "/var/log/applogs/spring-cloud-dataflow/Log.log",
"logger_name" => "decurtis.dxp.deamon.JobConfiguration",
"message" => {
"timeStamp" => "2018-01-30",
"severity" => "ERROR",
"hostname" => "",
"commonUtility" => {},
"offset" => "Etc/UTC",
"messageCode" => "L_9001",
"correlationId" => "ea5b13c3-d395-4fa5-8124-19902e400316",
"componentName" => "dxp-deamon-refdata-country",
"componentVersion" => "1",
"message" => "Unhandled exceptions",
},
"tags" => [
[0] "webapp-log",
[1] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
[2] "_jsonparsefailure"
]
}
```

I want my @metadata field in elasticsearch output.
Below is my conf file:

```
input {
dead_letter_queue {
path => "/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"
commit_offsets => true
pipeline_id => "main"
}
}
filter {
json {
source => "message"
}
mutate {
rename => { "[@metadata][dead_letter_queue][reason]" => "reason" }
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "elasticsearch"
manage_template => false
index => "deadletterlog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
}
```

Now in my output there is a field called "reason" but without any content. Is there something i am missing.

Comment: The idea of @metadata field is to have something temporary that does not show up in the output. In this particular case further, the reason says it cannot index the event into elasticsearch. Not sure how you can put it into Elasticsearch.

Comment: @sammy Well, logstash has this feature of "dead-letter-queue" which allow us to input those events which are giving 400 or 404 error, so they are indexed through dead letter queue input through different pipeline config. While i am taking input through dead letter queue and trying to put it into elasticsearch, i am trying to put metadata fields into my output through renaming it.

Comment: You cannot rename fields under metadata. It is issue 77 for the mutate filter at github and has been open a couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

this can help :-

```
mutate {
    add_field => {
        "reason" => "%{[@metadata][dead_letter_queue][reason]}"
        "plugin_id" => "%{[@metadata][dead_letter_queue][plugin_id]}"
        "plugin_type" => "%{[@metadata][dead_letter_queue][plugin_type]}"
    }
}
```